# Saved CC not working in magento

Tags: php, javascript, magento

My saved credit card payment option works well in default magento theme but not working in a custom theme. When we click on  "Credit Card (saved)" option nothing happens. No textbox or dropdown is showing up with options to enter card details.

When we click to proceed to next step,the validation error pops up as usual.

I think some where javascript is breaking up. But error console shows no errors as well! Can anyone point out what may be the possible reasons with this error? What is the js needed to get Saved credit card option work?

I am getting this error in a jquery-mobile theme and my header has following parameters..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/ccard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous/builder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous/controls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous/slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/varien/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/varien/form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/varien/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/varien/payment.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/varien/product.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mage/translate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mage/cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mage/directpost.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mage/captcha.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mage/centinel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/varien/weee.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="skin/frontend/mytheme/default/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="skin/frontend/mytheme/default/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="skin/frontend/mytheme/default/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="skin/frontend/mytheme/default/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="skin/frontend/mytheme/default/additional.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="skin/frontend/mytheme/default/mobilephone.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="skin/frontend/mytheme/default/mobiletheme.css" media="all" />
```

Here additional.js is `Jquery.noConflict();` file.

Am I missing something?

If anyone can point out something, please share.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your Javascript?
What events are attached to the checkbox?

Comment: Yes.. I m checking now. It seems the payment list ul having id "payment_form_ccsave" is display:none.... The javascript is not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out Why it happens.

The jquery styles were missing in the page. So I gave a create event `jQuery('#co-payment-form').trigger("create");` in checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml It conflicts the javascript of credit cards.

When I remove the create event. the code works well But Jquery-mobile styles are still missing. I need the styles too.

If anyone knows how to Overcome this situation please share it.